# Common scaling for ticks and extra ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

How can I tell pgfplots that I want the same scaling (number format) for `xtick` and `extra x ticks`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick={0.002,0.003},
        extra x ticks={0.001},   
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047) (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3.2e-3,0.503511)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the plot above I want the x tick on the left to be `1` since `10^{-3}` is factored out.

Comment: have you tried to set maximum values `xmax` and `ymax`?

Comment: yes, this has no effect

Comment: perhaps you will find what you are looking for in de [pgfmanual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) in `section 74.1` (beginning on page 719)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I now use a custom style and avoid drawing the scale factor twice.

Not ideal: you can manually set the same scaling for both types of ticks:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{improved scaled ticks/.style 2 args={
    scaled #1 ticks=#2,
    extra #1 tick style={
        scaled #1 ticks=#2,
        #1tick scale label code/.code=,
    },
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick={0.002,0.003},
        extra x ticks={0.001},
        improved scaled ticks={x}{base 10:3},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047) (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3.2e-3,0.503511)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You can also use `true` in place of `base 10:3`, but I suppose that in this case, pgfplots will independently choose both scales, which would be a mess if it came up with different results.

I defined a custom style so the scaling at least doesn't need to be specified twice. Also, by default, the scale factor would be drawn twice, so I use the `*tick scale label code/.code` key to suppress drawing it for the extra ticks.

Comment: Thx. This is not as automated as I hoped. I will leave the question open for a few more days and check yours correct there is no better solution.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt: After reading the pgfplots manual again, I believe that `improved scaled ticks={x}{true}` should be safe because the automatic scaling depends on the axis limits, not the values of the used ticks. But maybe a more beautiful solution can still be found :-)